# How does firejail build its default blacklist?

Tags: firejail

When I start `firejail`, i see my complete home directory. When I start `firejail --whitelist=~/something`, i see only `something` in my home.
Now i would like to restrict more access to the system. I can for example add `--blacklist=/media` and it works as expected.

But how does the default behaviour determine that `/home/OTHERUSER` and `/home/*` except the whitelisted files is hidden?
I do not see a matching rule in `/etc/firejail/*`.

And are allowed subdirectories possible? For example `--blacklist=/media --whitelist=/media/data` does not work as expected, even when the manpage tells, that whitelist overrides other options like `--read-only`.

Are these rules hardcoded in the binary? If not, which rule does these things?

An example what i would like to have. Basic rules:

1. Home empty, except for the things listed in the profile
2. Blacklist `/media/data`
3. Allow symlink `~/apps ->/media/data/apps` read-only.
4. Allow `/media/data/apps` (if neccesary) read-only.

1, 2 are working, 3 is only working with 4 (probably okay), but overriding read-access for a subdirectory of a forbidden directory does not work.

It seems a bit counter intuitive that it should work, but on the filesystem layer `mkdir -p foo/bar;chmod 111 foo;ls foo/bar/` (where `111` means, that there is no read (dir-listing) permission on foo, but only the executable bit (entering subdirectories) works, even when `ls foo/` fails.

The extended scenario would disallow all but a whitelist (profile + /usr, /bin, /lib, etc.). Another thing which doesn't seem possible without root (and then the app itself runs as root) is to replace i.e. /etc/passwd with one which doesn't contain users, which should not be known in the jail. `/etc` contains quite a lot of readable data, which should be hidden from untrusted applications.

But possibly the extended scenario would really justify a full chroot + userspace-lxc container.

Comment: Firejail hard-codes _a lot_ of rules in the binary, that's true. It distinguishes /home/user, /tmp, /tmp/.X11-unix, /dev and lots of other special dirs. About `whitelist` -- it only overrides `read-only`, not `blacklist`.

Comment: I saw, there is an additional ``noblacklist`` option, but it seems not to work for all things you may want to do. I add a full scenario to the question.